# How to run callback function after mapDispatchToProps OR update the props, using react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

### Here is an example of it.

My Code is:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onChangeHandler: (name,value) =>
    dispatch({ type: "REGISTRATION", key: name, value })
});
```

But I need something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onChangeHandler: (name,value) =>
    dispatch({ type: "REGISTRATION", key: name, value }).then((nextProps)=>console.log(nextProps))
});
```

Please help us.

Answer (score 1):

Redux data flow out of the box is synchronous, so it doesn't make sense to "then" a dispatch as it doesn't return anything. You can read more about that here:

https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-flow

I would recommend looking at redux-thunk which allows you to decide when to dispatch, whether it be sync or async, and will allow you to retrieve the updated state from the store. It does this by allowing you to dispatch a function instead of an action. The function provides you `dispatch` and `getState`.

Here is an example:

```
const onChangeHandler = (name, value) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Dispatch event
    dispatch({ type: "REGISTRATION", key: name, value });

    // Get updated state
    console.log("state :", getState());
};

export default connect(null, { onChangeHandler })(MyComponent);
```

If you are however looking at creating a side effect of the store updating from within your component, I would recommend to use the `useEffect` hook for this to respond to updates as a result of the redux store state updating your components props.

Here is an example:

```
const MyComponent = ({key, value}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`key or value updated: ${key} ${value}`);
    }, [key, value]);

    return (
        <span>Current props are {key} and {value}</span>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
  addToCartHandler:data=>dispatch(addToCart(data)),
  removeToCartHandler:data=>dispatch(removeToCart(data))
})
```